# What's an efficient way of letting a user know how to improve a question?

Tags: discussion, questions

What's an efficient and pragmatic way of letting a user know how to improve a question?

I'm thinking specifically of things like:

- Adding background info
- Posting actual code instead of pseudocode
- Including actual and expected results
- Copy-pasting the above rather than paraphrasing or translating

You can ask for these things which is simple enough, but if the user doesn't know why it's helpful or important, they're less likely to understand what exactly to tell you, and they'll be less likely to volunteer that info in the future.

For example, if you ask about the error message, it's not at all obvious that "it says there's no such file or directory" is much less helpful than `cat: file : No such file or directory` (trailing space in the filename!) or `cat: No such file or directory` (PATH is not a good name for a variable!) or `: No such file or directory` (the script has carriage returns!)

Ways that aren't awesome include:

- Repetitively explaining why these things are helpful on a case-by-case basis
- Burdening the user with the esr smart questions guide
- Wishfully thinking that the user will just pick it up by linking to a great example

My first thought would be to take an existing or write a new high quality question, and annotating it with what each part is and (importantly) what makes this specific part helpful. You can then say "Can you please include the output you're getting and the output you expected? See the example [here]."

It would be both a good example for how to post, and allow a user to compare it to their own question with a focus on the right aspects.

Comment: Point the user to http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve?

Comment: http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: All linked from http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @DavidPostill The reason I listed "Burdening the user with the esr smart questions guide" as a not-awesome way of doing it -- and I take it you disagree -- is that asking the user to read and digest walls of text doesn't seem like a good user experience for someone who thought they just wrote a fair question

Comment: "But [it said I need to add more details that are not code](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30652132/2564301)!!"

Comment: @Jongware - WOW.

Comment: _take an existing or write a new high quality question, and annotating it with what each part is and (importantly) what makes this specific part helpful._ - That's not a bad idea. Examples of bad questions for each of the close reasons would probably be useful too. Are you proposing a new Help page, editing existing Help pages, or just wanting to know if pointing to a blog post for this is OK?

Comment: @BSMP The benefit of annotating a question is that you provide an actual example in situ. There are blog posts and help pages covering these various topics, usually in long, dense prose (like some of the urls posted here), but "find/create simple, convenient help pages and keep the list handy" is certainly a valid answer.

Comment: And for completeness, another valid answer is "No, it's fine to tell the user to read a [22 page guide](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) on how to ask if they don't do it right the first time. Don't underestimate their willingness to learn." It's certainly efficient for me, it just seemed unwelcoming.

Comment: I think [ask], as @DavidPostill linked to, is a reasonable thing to have people read when they are having an issue with crafting a question. That's nowhere near 22 pages, and includes many of the items you've mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found people to be most receptive to advice when they see others taking ownership in their eventual success. The best way to do this is *edit* whatever you can, indicate why you changed what you did in the edit summary and then leave a comment letting the user know what else they need to do.

> I've helped [link to revision]fix the code formatting, made a few grammatical corrections and made some minor changes[/link] to make your question a little easier to read. But, in order to get an answer quickly, we need the *exact* error message you're seeing, because this could be due to a multitude of things and it's the only way to tell.

You've gotten the ball rolling for them. Their question now looks nicer, and while they're not yet getting answers, *holy cow someone thought this interesting enough to edit*.

That's quite a bit of effort right there, and more than sufficient *if* the user is still actively interested in getting an answer. Sometimes folks see something in the 'related' list after posting and don't come back for weeks, since they already got an answer (this is a big source of congestion in the helper queue).

If they engage again, they're probably not in that bucket, and can probably be helped. By leaving such a detailed comment, you've also made it *much* easier for someone else that notices the question to jump in and help out, alleviating you of a sense of obligation to kind of 'hover' over it until the user responds.

I agree with much of what [Makoto said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296101/50049) when it comes to building the person up. Jumping in and taking some ownership in the question through editing is a *great* way to do that.

Now, not *everything* can be edited if the only thing wrong is missing information, but the *vast majority* of questions by new users could at least use a slightly better title, and other minor polish - usually a bit more.

Comment: So in short, "repetitively requesting more information is inevitable, so invest enough in each case so that it happens once per user and not once per question". Fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

Don't focus on everything wrong with the post; build them up so that they are at least understand why you're fussing at them as opposed to giving them a solution.

Most questions that I see that are broken (but have a chance) are missing a few key things, like expected output, current input (to produce the output), or a backround explanation as opposed to, "it doesn't work".

If you ask for information one step at a time and have the person mend their question in that way, you would get them to improve on that particular instance.

Making it *stick* is ***much*** harder.  If it persists, then a few words of caution about their question quality in that instance would suffice, as well as a downvote and/or close vote.  If they don't listen to the words of advice begging them to improve, then the system will eventually lock them out.

Comment: I mentioned why I thought a simple "Can you include the error you're getting?" without further explaining how and why might not necessarily be the best way to do it. Are you saying that you consider this to be the best way anyways?

Comment: Yes.  The user has to be able to talk through their problem in such a way that another person can effectively respond to it.  Not just that, but there are scenarios/snippets of code in which it is impossible to ascertain what error they're getting, so asking for that is perfectly acceptable (and in my mind, the right way to go about it).

Comment: That's fair. So if I'm understanding you correctly, your preferred type of dialogue would e.g. be "Can you include the error you're getting?",  "It says there's no such file or directory", "Can you copy-paste it?", "No such file or directory" "Can you include anything before and after it as well?", "That's all it says", "Could it be that it actually starts with a colon?", "Yes", "Ok, the problem is that ...". This would be preferred over e.g. "Can you copy-paste the complete output? This is helpful since we can sometimes glean a lot information from tiny differences in punctuation and spacing"

Comment: Take it case by case.  There are some errors that I'd usually be curt about, such as the FileNotFoundException ("Are you *sure* that the file exists there?").  The main idea is that you're trying to get them to build their question into something that is more complete than what you first saw.  Asking them to edit the details into the question is a plus as it guides them along that path; they should be updating their question as opposed to flooding a ton of comments with what their problem is.

Comment: I'm very surprised. You seem to be recommending against saying why you ask for this additional information, while I strongly considered the value of that as a given (and the original question was about how to provide this value in a simple way).

Comment: The value is implicit as opposed to explicit; you're a person that doesn't know their program from Adam's program, yet you don't mind giving them a hand.  I don't feel that explaining why you're asking for the information is of much value since the intent is apparent; you can't understand what it is they're asking without it, and their question risks being closed if it's not provided in some cases.

Comment: The way I figured it, there are many reasons why you would e.g. ask for actual output. "They are probably on mobile and can't test the posted code" becomes "I'll run it for them this time, since this is a special case". "People are often too lazy to run the code themselves." becomes "I'll include the output if the code isn't straight forward." Meanwhile, "The code might be totally fine, but there could be problems with my setup and invocation" becomes "I should always include the exact output I get" which is the helpful one. Granted, this is often more helpful for bash than e.g. java questions